# Three.js model not displaying, but receive no error in console

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, model

I have HTML code, where I try to load models, that it looks something like this http://viskalia.fsv.cvut.cz/projekt/modely/orlova/orlova.html where u load model and use web to manipulate it.
Now the site loads, but the model is not showing. in console I see no errors. I am completely new to this, where is the mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>3D Model Viewer</title>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    canvas { display: block; background-color: #ffffff; } /* Nastavení bílého pozadí */
  </style>
  <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
    import { OrbitControls } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import { MTLLoader } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
    import { OBJLoader } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

    let camera, scene, renderer, controls;
    let parts = {};

    function init() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position.set(2, 2, 2);

      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff); /* Nastavení bílého pozadí */
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enableDamping = true;

      loadModel();
    }

    function loadModel() {
      const modelParts = [
        { name: 'cepice', objFile: 'models/cepice.obj', mtlFile: 'models/cepice.mtl' },
        { name: 'kniha', objFile: 'models/kniha.obj', mtlFile: 'models/kniha.mtl' },
      ];

      modelParts.forEach(part => {
        new MTLLoader().load(part.mtlFile, materials => {
          materials.preload();
          new OBJLoader()
            .setMaterials(materials)
            .load(part.objFile, object => {
              object.visible = true;
              parts[part.name] = object;
              scene.add(object);

              if (Object.keys(parts).length === modelParts.length) {
                createMenu();
                animate();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
              }
            });
        });
      });
    }

    function createMenu() {
      let menu = document.createElement('div');
      menu.style.position = 'absolute';
      menu.style.top = '10px';
      menu.style.right = '10px';
      menu.style.zIndex = '10';
      menu.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';
      menu.style.padding = '10px';
      menu.style.borderRadius = '5px';

      Object.keys(parts).forEach(name => {
        let label = document.createElement('label');
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'checkbox';
        input.checked = true;
        input.addEventListener('change', () => {
          parts[name].visible = input.checked;
        });
        label.appendChild(input);
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` ${name}`));
        menu.appendChild(label);
        menu.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      });
      document.body.appendChild(menu);
    }

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      controls.update();

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    init();
 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish to load model same as this http://viskalia.fsv.cvut.cz/projekt/modely/orlova/orlova.html
and move it around.
tried searching web and didnt find an answer